# Restoring past purchases with changed Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, itunes-store

How can I restore my past purchases if I wish to change my Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

At the Moment there is no Option to merge two iTunes Accounts ...

BUT:

- you can redownload from the old and purchase with the new one
- if you only want to change your e-Mail as "Account" everything is the same.

Comment: Thx. Truly I want to change my email in the Apple ID. So can I really restore my past purchases?

Comment: Yes this will be no Problem ;) if u only change the email on https://appleid.apple.com/ :) i have done it an nothing changed (except of the mail to login).   Don't forget to Vote and Mark as Solved :)